# How to set start position for negative column chart with Highcharts JS?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible in HighchartsJS to set the starting position for negative values, for example 200. So that the chart less than 200 is drawn down. By default position starts from zero.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change a base level, use `series.threshold` property.

**Example:**

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        threshold: 100
    }
},
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3c9tngod/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.threshold